# Fast app switching in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, fast-app-switching

How can i test whether or not  fast app switching has been implemented well in my windows phone 8 app?

I just added "Activation Policy=Resume " in my WPAppMamifest.xml file. Is it enough?

I want Fast app switching and not fast app resume

Comment: Changing that setting is fast app resume. Here is a [great blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/09/19/windows-phone-fast-app-resume.aspx) about it

Comment: Fast app switching is activated by default.

Comment: It is up to OS to decide to suspend or keep your app in memory. You can not implement fast app switching. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202866(v=vs.105).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465110.aspx) should help.